# Slim 3 parameter with slash

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

I have an API built with Slim 3, a route is defined as

```php
$app->get('/usage/{protocol}', function(Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
  $protocol = !empty($args['protocol']) ? sanitize($args['protocol']) : null;
  // do something...
});
```

My problem is that the `protocol` parameter can have a slash character in it multiple times `/` i.e.: `2022-123/A/B/C`.

When I make a request for `http://example.com/api/usage/2022-123/A/B/C` I get the following error:

> GET `http://example.com/api/usage/2022-123/A/B/C` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response.

How do I fix this so that it treats the whole text as one parameter?

Comment: / is a URL path seperator and has a special meaning. As far as I know this is not supported. There are other not supported characters like a dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$app->get('/usage[/{protocol:.*}]', function(Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
  $protocol = $request->getAttribute('protocol')
  // do something...
});
```

Comment: Thank you this works! Is there a documentation for this so I can read more about it? I'm wondering if I should use `$request->getAttribute()` for every parameter even if I'm not using the `:.*` trick here.